# How to keep a Html element Position intact and don't allow to change its position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below are 2 images. when i hove over "Roles" i want to increase the padding and also don't want the "add roles" button to change its position. is there any way to stop that.

**When i Don't Hover over Roles**

[image]

**When i hover over roles.**

[image]

**Below are my HTML and CSS Codes for Ref**

```
<ul class="tab-group">
    <li class="tab active"><a href="#roles">Roles</a></li>
    <li class="tab "><a href="#user">User</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="tab-onebtn">
    <li class="logouttab"> <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Login/logout" style="float: left;"> Add Role </a> </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.tab-group {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 40px 0;
}

.tab-group:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.tab-group li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: rgba(160, 179, 176, 0.25);
    color: #a0b3b0;
    font-size: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 14.25%;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
    transition: .5s ease;
}

.tab-group li a:hover {
    background: #179b77;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 8px;
}

.tab-group .active a {
    background: #1ab188;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.tab-content>div:last-child {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: You have set `padding: 8px;` in your `.tab-group li a:hover` which will apply `8px` padding to all top, left, right and bottom, try removing that.

Comment: i want that effect that is the reason i have kept. and i don't want the below element to shift its position. that was question as well.

Comment: In that case, Can you try changing your current padding in `.tab-group` from `padding: 0;` to `padding: 0px;` keeping the `padding: 8px;`  in your `.tab-group li a:hover` class ?

Comment: that is because i want to increase the padding when hovering and highlighting it. an it also produces a transition effect of sliding down. Hope i was clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is the Roles appearing bigger when hovered  you can use something like :

```
.tab-group li a:hover {
   background: #179b77;
   color: #ffffff;
   transform:scale(1.1);
}
```

instead of adding padding

Comment: this was good thanks. Can i learn different such effects possible either from you or any link.

Comment: http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/#effects . This guy has done an awesome job..check it out

Answer (score 2):

just remove padding `on:hover` state

```
.tab-group li a:hover {
  background: #179b77;
  color: #ffffff;
  /*padding: 8px;*/
}
```

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/245nj9kn/)**